# How to create a borderless form with System menu?

Tags: c#, interop, wndproc, createparams

I have created a border less form, I managed to assign the system menu to it using:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
            param.Style |= (WS_SYSMENU);

            return param;
        }
    }
```

But now, when I run it, it no longer shows the custom resizing zones I have set via WMNCHITTEST, like this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
        const int htBottomLeft = 16;
        const int htBottomRight = 17;
        if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
        {
            int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 40 && pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 40 && clientSize.Height >= 40)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(htBottomRight);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    }
```

So, how to overcome this? Is it possible to have a borderless form with system menu which also respects the WMNCHITTEST?

Comment: Anyone? And just 9 views in almost a day...

Answer (score 0):

This `CreateParams` override should do the trick:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style = WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU;
        cp.ClassStyle = CS_DBLCLKS;
        return cp;
    }
}

const int WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x2000000;
const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;
const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
```